# Does a שור מועד return to תם status when its location is changed?

Tags: halacha

The gemorah had stated in Bava Kamma that if the owner of the ox changes the ox returns to its original status as a Tam. Does the same hold true if the Ox was a Mu'ad in Israel and then was moved to Bavel does it go back to being a Tam?

Answer (score 1):

No, and indeed that came up in yesterday's Daf Yomi ([Bava Kamma 84b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.84b.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

> וְהָאָמַר רָבָא: אֵין מוּעָד בְּבָבֶל! אָמְרִי: דְּאִיַּיעַד הָתָם וְאַיְּיתוּהּ לְהָכָא
>
> But doesn’t Rava say: There are no forewarned oxen in Babylonia, as an ox can be forewarned only by ordained judges? The Sages say in response: This is a case where an ox was forewarned there, in Eretz Yisrael, and then its owners brought it here, to Babylonia.

(The Gemara ends up saying that in this case the Babylonian judges, who don't have the original semichah, can't judge the case, as it's an unusual one. But the point that the ox remains muad isn't contested.)